# How can I improve this queries speed?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq

I have a table with a list of customers.
One customer has 0, 1 or more contract(s).

I must retrieve all the enabled customer, set them in a DTO and add the current contract to this DTO (If there is one)

For the moment, it is very slow (more than 10min).

**CODE**

```
List<CustomerOverviewDto> result = new List<CustomerOverviewDto>();    
customers= context.Customers.Where(c => c.IsEnabled).ToList();
    foreach (Customer customer in customers)
    {
        CustomerOverviewDto customerDto = GetCustomer(customer);
        Framework.Contract contract =
            customer.Contracts.Where(c => c.ContractEndDate >= DateTime.Today && c.ContractStartDate <= DateTime.Today)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        if (contract != null)
        {
            SetContract(customerDto, contract);
        }
        result.add(customerDto);
    }
```

Comment: Show generated SQL query

Comment: Customer table contains 36 columns (Varchar and Int) and there is 14478 rows. Do you really need the name of the column ?

Comment: I want to see how ORM genereate query, maybe it do in very inefficient way. By the way make sure your query isn't blocked by another transaction

Comment: Do you have indexes on IsEnabled, ContractEndDate and ContractStartDate? Also, what does SetContract do? these pieces of info are pretty important to understand why the query is not efficient

Comment: @lad2025 How can I see this generated query ? In visual studio ?

Comment: also, by using .ToList() in the first line you are loading that whole table into memory before working on it, try taking that off for a start,,

Comment: @NickDewitt There is no index on those columns. Set contract only add the contract to CustomerOverViewDTO

Comment: @NickDewitt Adding an index will slow the insert in those tables, am I right ?

Comment: Yes but barely, the read performance will be worth it

Comment: Where does `customers` come from? What does `GetCustomer()` do? Does it query the database?

Comment: @Weedoze What is the `result.Count` at the end (i.e. how many customer records does your procedure load for those 2min)?

Comment: @JørgenFogh I forgot to change the variable name : `customer` is `result` . GetCustomer() as explained create an OverviewDTO which retrieve only certain column. It query the database

Comment: @IvanStoev There is 14386 rows

Comment: You still haven't changed it everywhere. Please make sure that your code compiles before you ask your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use projection to only return the columns you work with by using "Select". If you have 36 columns this will give you better results.

```
customers= context.Customers.Where(c => c.IsEnabled).Select(cust => new Customer
{
    Id = cust .Id
}).ToList();
```

https://www.talksharp.com/entity-framework-projection-queries

After that check in the queryplan if you have table scans or index scans. Try to avoid them by setting apropriate indexes.

Comment: I cant create CustomerOverviewDTO on the first query because I need to retrieve the customer's contract which is not in CustomerOverviewDTO

Comment: You don't need to change the Customer implementation, just the query. See my edit with the sample.

Answer (score 1):

I think the the problem is the query that retrieves the contract inside the loop. It would be better to retrieve all the data with one query like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Today;
var query =
    from customer in context.Customers
    where customer => customer.IsEnabled
    select new 
    {
        customer,
        contract = customer.Contracts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ContractEndDate >= date && c.ContractStartDate <= date)
    };
var result = new List<CustomerOverviewDto>();
foreach (var entry in query)
{
    CustomerOverviewDto customerDto = GetCustomer(entry.customer);
    if (entry.contract != null)
        SetContract(customerDto, entry.contract);
    result.add(customerDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all, when you use .ToList(), you are executing the query right there, and pulling back every row that IsEnabled into the memory for working on. You want to do more on the database side.

```
result = context.Customers.Where(c => c.IsEnabled); //be lazy
```

Secondly, the query is only going to perform well and be optimised by the execution engine properly if it has indexes to work with.

Add some indexes on the fields that you are performing comparisons on.

Think about this line of code for example

```
    customer.Contracts.Where(c => c.ContractEndDate >= DateTime.Today && 
c.ContractStartDate <= DateTime.Today).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is you don't have a foreign key from customers to contracts, and you have no indexes on ContractStartDate and ContractEndDate it is going to perform extremely poorly and is going to be run once for every customer that 'IsEnabled'

Comment: He iterates through `customers`, not `result`. Lazyness would buy him nothing in this snippet.

Comment: ok yeah good point, but result still contains every row (the work is done and the data returned to the variable by .toList() ), and we don't know how Customers was populated either

Comment: True. However, the OP writes: "... I must retrieve all the enabled customer ..." There is no way to avoid loading all the data which is part of the output. It might be useful to use eager loading but we need more information to give a useful answer.

Comment: yeah I agree, we need to see how customers is populated. well spotted, I need to go smoke!

Comment: Er his post just changed result to customers

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the variable name... my bad

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only want to do some thing when returns a value. So you can add this in you initial query, and include the contracts:

```
customers= context.Customers
                           .Include(c => c.Contracts)
                           .Where(c => c.IsEnabled
                                     && c.Contracts.Any(con => con.ContractEndDate >= DateTime.Today && con .ContractStartDate <= DateTime.Today))
                           .ToList();

 foreach (Customer customer in customers)  
 {
    CustomerOverviewDto customerDto = GetCustomer(customer);
    Framework.Contract contract =
    customer.Contracts.Where(c => c.ContractEndDate >= DateTime.Today && c.ContractStartDate <= DateTime.Today)
        .First();
    SetContract(customerDto, contract);
 }
```

Comment: Wrong. I have to retrieve all the customer even if they dont have a current contract

Comment: That is not clear in your code, however when you include the contracts it will do less roundtrips to your db.

Comment: I can't call Include after the where

Answer (score 0):

As I have no idea of what your domain model structure looks like or why you are not using navigation properties to map the CURRENT contract to the customer, you could do something like this.

You could do just 2 roundtrips to the database by materializing all the customers and contracts and then mapping them in memory to your DTO objects. Assuming you have CustomerId as FK and Customer.Id as PK.

```
List<CustomerOverviewDto> result = new List<CustomerOverviewDto>();    

customers = context.Customers.Where(c => c.IsEnabled).ToList();
contracts = context.Contracts.Where(c => c.ContractEndDate >= DateTime.Today && c.ContractStartDate <= DateTime.Today).ToList();

foreach (Customer customer in customers)
{
    var customerDto = GetCustomer(customer);
    var contract = contracts.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customer.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (contract != null)
    {
        SetContract(customerDto, contract);
    }

    result.add(customerDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by using 1 query and projection

```
context.Customers.Where(c => c.IsEnabled).Select(c => new CustomerOverviewDto{...}).ToList();
```

I directly retrieve the contract when creating the CustomerOverviewDto